# How to change series name in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, charts, series

I have a series of charts I am creating using VBA (code below).

I am having trouble changing the names of the series from series 1 and series 2 to Current State and Solution State.

I keep getting an

> Object Variable or With Block Variable not set

error.

However without the `srs1` and `srs2` code the charts work just fine (just with the wrong series names).

I looked up how to fix this and the answer I received however is not working for me.
Does anyone know another way to do this?

```
Sub MA()
    Dim Srs1 As Series
    Dim Srs2 As Series
    Dim i  As Integer
    Dim MAChart As Chart
    Dim f As Integer
    f = 2 * Cells(2, 14)
     For i = 1 To f Step 2
        Set MAChart = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart(Left:=750, Width:=400, Top:=130 + 50 * (i - 1), Height:=100).Chart
         With MAChart
         .PlotBy = xlRows
         .ChartType = xlColumnClustered
         .SetSourceData Source:=ActiveSheet.Range("Q" & 1 + i & ":Z" & 2 + i)
         .Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = 4
         .Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = 0
         .HasTitle = True
         .ChartTitle.Text = "Provider Load for " & Cells(i + 1, 15)
         'where errors start- works fine up to this point
         Set Srs1 = ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1) 
         Srs1.Name = "Current State"
         Set Srs2 = ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2) 
         Srs2.Name = "Proposed Solution"
         End With
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: There is no active chart. Use `Set Srs1 = .SeriesCollection(1)` etc.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try changing these lines ...

```
     Set Srs1 = ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1) 
     Srs1.Name = "Current State"
     Set Srs2 = ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2) 
     Srs2.Name = "Proposed Solution"
```

To ...

```
     .SeriesCollection(1).Name = "Current State"
     .SeriesCollection(2).Name = "Proposed Solution"
```

You are already using `MAChart` inside your With block so you should be able to access it's `.SeriesCollection(x).Name` properties in the same fashion as you have done for the other properties.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the problem is with referencing - in the code you reference ActiveChart (I am guessing it does not exist), while you have created MAChart in the code above.

```
 Set Srs1 = MAChart.SeriesCollection(1) 
 Srs1.Name = "Current State"
 Set Srs2 = MAChart.SeriesCollection(2) 
 Srs2.Name = "Proposed Solution"
```

Comment: Or just `Set Srs1 = .SeriesCollection(1)` etc.